# How to make OnTouchListener such a way that it works only once?

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener

Having an OnTouchListener, set on a text view, i want it to work only once when user pressed text view , and nothing should happen when he presses it again.

Comment: You can disable/enable the touch event of the View for it..

Comment: Have you tried anythings ? you should supply some code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have perform your work in onTouch, do something like this

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(null);
```

your view will no more response to touch listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply set the listener to `null`:

```
   someView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                someView.setOnTouchListener(null);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

or:

```
 someView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                someView.setOnClickListener(null);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener {

    int touchedCount = 0

    boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (touchedCount < 1) {
            // do whatever you want to do once here
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a

```
Boolean stuff = true;
```

and in your onClickListener you check for it

```
public void onClick(){
   if(stuff){
      stuff = !stuff;
      //do things
   }
}
```

This will only execute methods called in the if-statement once.